# swiftyJson error handle

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire, swifty-json

I got problem with SwiftyJson, I am trying to check if there is any value in my Json which contain "Access denied" and print it, but it's not checking, what's wrong with my code?

Json response I get is:

> {
>       error =     {
>           code = "-32002";
>           message = "Access denied";
>       };
>       id = 1;
>       jsonrpc = "2.0"; }

**Request method:**

```
 private func makeWebServiceCall (urlAddress: String, requestMethod: HTTPMethod, params:[String:Any], completion: @escaping (_ JSON : Any) -> ()) {

    manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 1


    manager.request(urlAddress, method: requestMethod, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON{ response in

        print(response.timeline)

        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):

            let json = JSON(value)

            if (json["error"].arrayValue.contains("Access denied")) {
                print("Access denied")
            }

            if let jsonData = response.result.value {


                completion(jsonData)
            }


        case .failure(let error):

                completion("Failure Response: \(error)")



}
```

Comment: `json["error"]` contains a dictionary `{}`. An array is represented by `[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json["error"]` is `Dictionary` not `Array` and you need to access the `message` value from that dictionary.

```
if let message = json["error"]["message"].string, message == "Access denied" {
     print("Access denied")
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I need!

Comment: @EgleMatutyte Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
if let message = json["error"]["message"].rawString(), message == "Access denied" {

    print(message)
}
```